# UnsatisfiedLinkError When sending compressed (snappy) message to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, snappy

In my java web app I'm sending messages to [kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html).

I would like to compress my messages before sending it so I'm setting in my producer properties:

props.put("compression.codec", "2");

As I understand "2" stands for snappy, but when sending a message I'm getting:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(I)I
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(Native Method)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.maxCompressedLength(Snappy.java:316)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:66)
        at kafka.message.SnappyCompression.<init>(CompressionUtils.scala:61)
        at kafka.message.CompressionFactory$.apply(CompressionUtils.scala:82)
        at kafka.message.CompressionUtils$.compress(CompressionUtils.scala:109)
        at kafka.message.MessageSet$.createByteBuffer(MessageSet.scala:71)
        at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet.<init>(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:44)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$3.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:94)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$3.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:82)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:190)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:45)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:95)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.map(HashMap.scala:45)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.serialize(DefaultEventHandler.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:44)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:116)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:95)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:71)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:526)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:70)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:41)
```

To resolve it I tried adding snappy dependency to my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
        <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
        <version>${snappy-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and add the jar to my jetty server under /lib/ext
but still getting this error.

If I set "0" instead of "2" in the "compression.codec" property I do not get the exception, as expected.

what should I do in order to be able to use snappy compression?

This is my snappy version (should I use a different one?):
        1.1.0.1

I'm deploying my app on jetty 8.1.9 which runs on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: The error occurs because Snappy can't load the native library. What OS and Snappy version are you using?

Comment: @Wildfire This is my snappy version (should I use a different one?):
  <snappy-version>1.1.0.1</snappy-version>

I'm deploying my app on jetty 8.1.9 which runs on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
        <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I had the same issue and the code above solves my problem. The jar contains native libraries for all OS. Below are my development environment:

```
JDK version:        1.7.0_76
Kafka version:      2.10-0.8.2.1
Zookeeper version:  3.4.6
```